# How to add coma in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How can i add coma after each digit in notepad++ ?
For example:

```
000000000
```

And I want to change it to body like this:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use replace with regular expression.
Use expression:

```
(\d)
```

and replace:

```
(\1),
```

The output:

> 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

[image]

Comment: You have an extra comma at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This will add a comma between 2 digits only, not at the beginning and not at the end.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\d)(?=\d)`
- Replace with: `,`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\d)     # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a digit before
(?=\d)      # positive look ahead, make sure we have a digit after
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: @voik3: Why did you remove the accepted mark? The other answer produce an extra comma at the end of the string, is this really what you want? Moreover, it replaces with `(\1),`, why parenthesis?